# which open source CAD?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, cad

I need a 3D CAD software that permits to create parts and assembly.
Right now, I try FreeCad, Salome and BRL-CAD.
The first one can create only single parts, not assembly.
Salome have the same problem.
BRL-CAD can create parts and assembly, but it's use is not intuitive and the graphical module right now is not mature.
Any other?

Comment: Free CAD *can* do assemblies, and is a solid choice. Look into Autodesk Fusion 360, too. Unfortunately this question is very broad and opinion based so I’m voting to close.

Comment: This looks like a [resource-hunting question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832) (more specificaly, a software recommendation question). Such questions are prone to becoming out-dated, and are therefore considered off-topic for this site. However, you can try asking it at [SoftwareRecs.SE], just make sure you read their [guidelines on asking a good question](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Answer (score 1):

Almost all the big Companies offer free version of their products for students. If you are a student, you could use Solidworks (12 month) or Inventor. 
For non students (or something comparable) I would recommend using trial versions of reputable software. From what I have experienced, free CAD software isn't all that great (at least for my purpose).

Comment: Not only is it not great, its also highly bad for you. Sure you saved a buck in the software but then you wasted several thousand elsewhere.